# How to get value from a JSON file using key?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am new to python. I am trying to get value from a JSON File.

Here is my JSON file stored in static/tokens.json

```
{
  "872387":"ABC",
  "821483":"XYZ",
  "575652":"KLM"
}
```

I want to read the get the value of Key(821483). which is XYZ.

Here is what I am doing

I am reading Json file

```
token = json.load(open(os.path.join(app.root_path, "static", "tokens.json")))
print(token['821483'])
```

But it gives me this error:

```
print(token['821483']) TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I have also tried this

```
with open(os.path.join(app.root_path, "static", "tokens.json")) as read_file:
  data = json.load(read_file)[1]
print("Type of deserialized data: ", type(data))
print(data['821483'])
```

But Again I am getting the same error.

I have seen similar questions on Stackoverflow. And what I have understood so far is that

```
tokens = json.load(open(os.path.join(app.root_path, "static", "tokens.json"))) converts Json to a List. How can I solve this problem? I don't want to change the structure of JSON file.
```

How can I convert this JSON file into a dictionary not into a list so that I can access the values using a key?

Comment: What data type is `tokens`? - `print(type(tokens)` - or simply `print(tokens)`.

Comment: <class 'list'> @wwii

Comment: In the first case you are assigning to `tokens` and using `print(**token**['821483'])`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: It's a typo @AbdulNiyasPM

Comment: I second @wwii I cannot reproduce. I get ``` token['821483'] 'XYZ' ``` .  Are you sure about the structure of ```tokens.json```. From the errors you are getting I'm suspecting the JSON in the file is actually an array of objects, that translates to a list of dicts after ```json.load()```.

Comment: The example you gave for the json file must not faithfully represent the actual file.  You said that `print(type(token))` returned `<class 'list'>` in a comment yet the Exception you included in the question indicates `token` is a string.  You should add the result of `print(token)` to your question.

Comment: If `json.load` is returning a string, there must be something about the JSON file we're not seeing from your excerpt of it.

Comment: `json.loads('{"872387":"ABC","821483":"XYZ","575652":"KLM"}')["821483"]` works as expected. There must be something more in the actual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `json.load()` python automatically converts to dict, [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) so you don't need to convert to dict again

```
import json
data = json.load(open("static/tokens.json"))
```

Now check what is in data and the **type** of data:

```
{'872387': 'ABC', '821483': 'XYZ', '575652': 'KLM'} <class 'dict'>
```

We sucessfully convert it to dict so now you can iterate:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    if key == "821483":
        print({key: value})

Out: {'821483': 'XYZ'}
```

If you don't want to iterate you can simply use `dict_object.get(value)`

```
print(data.get("821483"))
Out: XYZ
```

Comment: Do we have to iterate over a dictionary in python to get a value? I was hoping it works as a Map(Key-Value Pair) in Java. Is it not possible without iterating?

Comment: You can use `get(value)`, check the updated answer.

Comment: @RohitSingh - no - [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: Not clear how this answered the question, This is essentially the same *code* as the OP's example.